# Plotly raster images

Tags: r, plotly, raster, r-plotly

I am trying to plot raster images on plotly, and using this very [helpful book](https://plotly-book.cpsievert.me/raster-images.html) as a reference. Here's the code that has been used to produce the image in the link -

```
m <- matrix(hcl(0, 80, seq(50, 80, 10)), nrow = 4, ncol = 5)
r <- as.raster(m)
plot(r)
plot_ly() %>%
  layout(images = list(
    source = raster2uri(r), # converts a raster object to a data URI.
    xref = "x", yref = "y", x = 0, y = 0, sizex = 1, sizey = 1,
    sizing = "stretch", xanchor = "left", yanchor = "bottom"
  ))
```

Expected output (as per book) - 
[image: Y U NO DIS OUTPUT]

Actual output - 
[image]

Related - The [page at plotly](https://plot.ly/r/logos/) also does not seem to be particularly helpful in this case.

Does anyone know how to plot images in plotly?

Comment: I copy and pasted your code into my console, and it worked just fine. Maybe try reinstalling plotly?

Comment: I tried reinstalling plotly. No luck. Does the code mentioned here - https://plot.ly/r/logos/ also work well for you?

Comment: I can't tell. Sorry, that link returns a 404 for me. =|